# Set an environment variable in a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongohq

I want to set `MONGOHQ_URL` in my sinatra app in order to be able to do this:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'])
```

How do I setup the `MONGOHQ_URL`?

Comment: Is this because you want to go to a different URL on different machines (e.g. production machine, staging machine, development machine), or because you want to go to different URLs based on the deployment mode (e.g. development versus production)? If the former, you have your answer. If the latter...well, we can answer that, too.

Answer (score 9):

- on Windows: `set MONGOHQ_URL=test`
- on Unix (bash): `export MONGOHQ_URL=test`
- on Unix (csh): `setenv MONGOHQ_URL test`

Comment: In other words, you don't set the environment variable in Sinatra or via Ruby, but rather you set it on the machine you are using outside of Ruby/Sinatra.

Comment: They are not working in my case. Variables set once and automatically getting removed. I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

In order for your environment variables to always be available to your app, you will need to make sure they get exported whenever a new terminal session launches. It's common to put these in `.bashrc` for example

```
export MONGOHQ_URL=https://some.long.secure.url # for example
```

But for your local development purposes you might want to check out [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which allows you to store local environment variables in `.env` file in root of your project.  For production, you should be able to Figaro with Sinatra, for more see answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213138/sinatra-with-figaro-gem) or see [readme on the github repo](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

In general you should always make sure not to commit sensitive config information in your codebase so make sure to add any files like `.env` or `config/application.yml` to your `.gitignore` file.