# How to configure a sinatra rack app to use figaro

Tags: ruby, sinatra, figaro-ruby

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213138/sinatra-with-figaro-gem) and think something is missing or a change in version. I have a very simple rack app using [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) -- hosted with Heroku. Currently, Im on local machine.

I now need to use `ENV`.

My app structure:

```
APP
 |_ config/
 |_ public/
 |_ views/
 |_ config.ru
 |_ app.rb
 |_ other-files
```

Inside config/application.yml

```
SOME_KEY: some-value
```

Inside config.ru

```
require './app.rb'
run MyApp.run!
```

This the part this gives the error. Inside app.rb:

```
require  File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/application.yml'

[...]
```

This is the same line as in the link above. I get

> cannot load such file /config/application.yml

In `app.rb`, I need to be able to do `ENV['SOME_KEY']`

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before in a standalone app as follows:

```
Figaro.application = Figaro::Application.new(
  environment: 'production',
  path: File.expand_path("config/application.yml")
)
Figaro.load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just `require` a yaml file as it is not ruby.  Yaml is a file structure that is not ruby specific.  Figaro was also written to be used with Ruby on Rails, not Sinatra. You can probably figure out a way to make it work, but it's not as easy as just loading a yaml config file.

See this post for some ideas of how you might accomplish what you're trying to do. Here is a forked version of the gem which might work for you.

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/pull/229